# Redirecting to the referrer on form submission

Tags: php

There are multiple pages. There are links on these pages. These links leads to a page with a form. When the form is submitted, the page that holds the form refreshes itself to process the submitted data.

Here's the question.

When the page with the form receive the submitted data and process it, it should take the user back to the page that took him/her to the form page. How would you go about doing that using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I like to do is add to a session variable array each time a page is accessed called "history", and only add to the array if the last `$_SESSION['history']` item is not the current url (avoid multiple recent entries for page refresh, form validation failure, etc). Basically a breadcrumb trail of where the user has been. When you process the form - send the user back to whichever array value is most recent, excluding the current form's url if you please. Just make sure to set a default value in case there is no history.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can work sometimes, but Ive had major issues with it, and it doesn't work in a lot of cases (refresh, coming from same page, typing in the form url, coming from an email link, etc.) I strictly avoid it personally as it can lead to erratic behavior and redirect loops if you aren't careful with it. In fact I would just never use it for redirection.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. It seems like it could be used to address a variety of problems. Thanks!

Comment: I did  make the assumption here that you could figure out the code if you had the concept, am I probably right? I can share code if needed but I may be slow. I'd have to reverse engineer it into vanilla php.

Comment: Sure, I get it. Thanks again!

Comment: Just an afterthought I forgot to mention: Make sure you don't add to the history for any url that can't be redirected to properly, like a form action url or login/logout page. My general rule is not to set it until I am about to generate an HTML page.

Comment: Bad technique. Users can have opened 2 or more tabs with the same site simultaneously and you send him to nowhere. Situations described are meant serious for web form processor? How these situation are solved by SESSION variable, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This concept is known as [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  The question is: is the user always going back to the same static original page, or are there many pages that can lead the user to this form?  If the latter is true, simply add the referer (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) as a form element to record where they came from.  php code:

```
<?php
     class controller {
        //for chaining
        public static function _() { return new self; }
        public function GET() {
           //dispay form
        }
        public function POST() {
           //process form
           //add errors to session
           if (!empty($_SESSION['form errors']) {
              $this->redirect($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
           }
           else {
              $this->redirect("original-user-location", true, 303);
           }
        }
        private function redirect($loc) {
           header("Location: $loc", true, 303);
           exit;
        }
        //ignore PUT, DELETE
        public function __call($_, $_) {}
     }
     controller::_()->$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']();
  ?>
```

Comment: That's beautiful! I've been using cookies to do the same thing and this is so much more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't work, though, if the form data does not validate the first time and the form page is refreshed for a second time, would it?

Comment: You simply keep track of the user's form data in the session.  In GET fill in their inputs from that.  The user can refresh as much as they want now, it won't clear the session data.  You can do that later.